# Struts2:I assigned the value of a parameter but got a nullpointer error in jsp file

Tags: java, jsp, struts2

I use Java Struts2 to develop a simple project, I just got a wired nullpointer error, around the problem there are two jsp files and one java file.

In the first jsp file, I want to pass a parameter to the java file

In the java file, base on this value, I set the value of another parameter, which will be used in the second jsp file.

I was able to succeed using this method in other project, but the same way just doesn't work on this project.

Here are the details:

My configuration struts.xml:

```
<action name="create_little_thing_choose_table"    class="little_thing_create.choose_table_java"   method="execute">
        <result name="SUCCESS">/create_little_thing_choose_table.jsp</result>
</action>
```

In the first jsp, I pass a parameter to java:

```
<form action=create_little_thing_choose_table>
    <p>User <input type="text" name="user_id" value="1999"> Create new thing</p>
    <input type="submit" value="Create" />
</form>
```

In my java file, I assign the value of a parameter "table_list"

```
        //do something here to get table_list
        //I have tried to print table_list here, it shows that the table_list is good here.
        ServletRequest request=ServletActionContext.getRequest();
        HttpServletRequest req =(HttpServletRequest) request;
        HttpSession sesssion=req.getSession();
        sesssion.setAttribute("table_list",table_list);
        return "SUCCESS";
```

In the second jsp file, I want to know the value of table_list using following code:

```
<%
String a=request.getAttribute("table_list").toString();
out.print(a);
%>
```

But I just got a 500 error saying that there is a nullpointer error in the code, why was the error? Can anyone help me? thanks in advance.

Comment: just a comment, while using struts try not to deal directly with `request` and `session`.. use action with proper `setter` and `getter` ( or a `ModelDriven` action) and let struts `populate` these parameters for you. Also In `jsp` there are lots of good `tags` which can be used instead of getting parameters from `request`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know the reason now, In my java file, I should directly use

```
table_list="blablabla" ;
```

to assign it, instead of

```
String table_list="blabla";
```